# jQuery get JSON feed from Facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get some json feed from a facebook page. Here's my code:

```
var myurl = "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=111222778066&format=json";
$.ajax({
    url: myurl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json){
      ...
    }
});
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error: (in page.php:2)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

This is attempting to query an RSS feed for a page. RSS feeds are officially deprecated. Some pages still have them grandfathered in, depending on the date the page was created, but you can't rely on them being there, nor can you detect if they are present or not.

This page seems to have a feed - for now, since the URL returns data.

Your error is a syntax error. Take a look at your console to see which line this is coming from. There is no guarantee that the unexpected colon is in the code snippet you posted.

To future proof your script, your best bet is to create an app, and query the page via the Graph API at this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/111222778066/feed?access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you authenticate as an app, you can get a permanent access token. Using the JavaScript SDK will automate this process for you.

These articles should get you started:

- [Login as an app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)
- [The Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api)
- [Facebook's JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue of the RSS feeds being deprecated as @cpilko mentions. Your issue is that facebook feeds don't support [jsonp](/questions/tagged/jsonp)hich relies on loading the data-url as as javascript that has a callback included, instead they only return plain [json](/questions/tagged/json), [atom](/questions/tagged/atom) or [rss2](/questions/tagged/rss2). Instead you'll need to proxy the feed through something else like your own backend or googles feed api:

```
<script>
  function jsapi_loaded(){
    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(
        "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=111222778066"
      );
      feed.setNumEntries(10);
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=jsapi_loaded" async></script>
```