# Facebook feed using Jsonp?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I have a personal facebook page which has restricted viewership i.e. its not a public page.
However the page belongs to me....
What I would like to do is access that page's feed using Jsonp with Graph API?
Is it possible?

Comment: I think you need an access token for it.

Comment: What kind of access token

Answer (score 1):

These questions (& answer(s)) might solve your question!

[get facebook page feed as json with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926659/get-facebook-page-feed-as-json-with-jquery)

[jQuery get JSON feed from Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283468/jquery-get-json-feed-from-facebook)

http://www.prettyklicks.com/blog/making-a-facebook-feed-using-the-graph-api-json-and-jquery/291/